# Collecting submitted value from an array of fields to validate in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on validating some `input[type='text']` using Codeigniter. All I want is to collect the value of those input and store them into an array. Here's my code :

```
<input type='text' value='FIRSTVALUE' name='tobevalidated[]'>
<input type='text' value='SECONDVALUE' name='tobevalidated[]'>
```

in my controller, I set the following code :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('tobevalidated[]', 'Lectures', 'validatingvalue');
```

And then I extend `CI_Form_validation` class to make the following code :

```
function validatingvalue($str){

   //some conditions

}
```

I want in the `validatingvalue` function, the submitted value becomes an array like :

$newarray = array('teacherid' => 'FIRSTVALUE', 'subjectid' => 'SECONDVALUE');

So I can do a validation like :

```
 if(in_array($newarray, $resultfromdb){
    return false;
 } else {
    return true;
 }
```

How do I achieve that?

### -----------------------------------------------------

I've tried in `validatingvalue` :

```
$newarray = array('teacherid' => $str['teacherid'], 'subjectid' => $str['subjectid']);
```

and created two input element like these :

```
<input type='text' value='FIRSTVALUE' name='tobevalidated['teacherid']'>
<input type='text' value='SECONDVALUE' name='tobevalidated['subjectid']'>
```

But it all failed and seemed to be very wrong.

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('tobevalidated', 'Lectures', 'validatingvalue');

Comment: and In my form? what should I write?